# How to collect geth's metrics?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I am trying to measure chain insert rates in a Geth node.

In a deprecated Go-ethereum [blog](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring), it says I can use `debug.metrics(false)` to get all available metrics (so I can use debug.metrics().chain.inserts to get insert rates).

However, that no longer holds. When I tested on the console, even with `--metrics` flag added in starting a Geth node, the console continues to complain the debug object "has no member 'metrics'".

Here is my output when I type "debug. ", and by the way, it shows a lot more than the options listed [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-debug#debug_writeblockprofile).

[image: Here is my output image when I type "debug. <tab>"]

I then went to the [codebase](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/855690523a6bd98ce2eef9489d9f76cf2bc3868c/core/blockchain.go#L64), and see metrics objects are still there. I am wondering how can I get some metrics reports as the outputs in the deprecated blog.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This changed with 1.9 I think you should read the release notes for more info

Comment: Which version of geth are you using?

Comment: You can try asking them too at https://discordapp.com/invite/nthXNEv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Geth 1.9, there were many changes to how metrics a monitored.
For example, the endpoint `geth --monitor` was completely removed.

To get the metrics from your node:

1. Run your geth node with the added flags `--metrics --pprof`
2. Navigate to `http://localhost:6060/debug/metrics`

Notice that if you are running geth on a remote system, you will need to adjust he IP address, enable the port on the firewall and adjust port forwarding if applicable.

The resulting web page should show something like this:

```sh
{
"chain/account/commits.50-percentile": 0,
"chain/account/commits.75-percentile": 0,
"chain/account/commits.95-percentile": 0,
"chain/account/commits.99-percentile": 0,
"chain/account/commits.999-percentile": 0,
"chain/account/commits.count": 67,
"chain/account/commits.fifteen-minute": 0.045282483590452616,
"chain/account/commits.five-minute": 0.06561088031274115,
"chain/account/commits.max": 0,
.
.
.
}
```

Reference blogpost
https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/07/10/geth-v1-9-0/

Comment: just to add that for prometheus you will need `http://localhost:6060/debug/metrics/prometheus`